# How to fetch more than 20 likelihood places from google place api for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I would like to fetch more than 20 likelihood places from google place api for iOS.

`findPlaceLikelihoodsFromCurrentLocation(withPlaceFields:callback:)` returns exactly 20 nearby places.

I cannot specify how many places and which types that I want to fetch.

javaScript api seems to be able to specify the radius and fetch 60 places.

Q1) Is there any way to fetch more than 20 likelihood places?

Q2) Is there any way to fetch places of certain types (e.g fetch 20 nearby supermarkets only)

```
let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) |
                                          UInt(GMSPlaceField.placeID.rawValue))!
placesClient?.findPlaceLikelihoodsFromCurrentLocation(withPlaceFields: fields, callback: {
  (placeLikelihoodList: Array<GMSPlaceLikelihood>?, error: Error?) in
  if let error = error {
    print("An error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return
  }

  if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
    for likelihood in placeLikelihoodList {
      let place = likelihood.place
      print("Current Place name \(String(describing: place.name)) at likelihood \(likelihood.likelihood)")
      print("Current PlaceID \(String(describing: place.placeID))")
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I also created a wrapper for this to fetch more than 20+ location, feel to have a look at https://github.com/tryWabbit/Google-Api-Helper .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Fetching more than 20 results is **not supported** within the ios SDK.

The only way around this would be switch to the [web API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search), and use json to filter your results. Within the JSON response there is a `pagetoken` field which you can append on and get all the results however, this requires multiple API calls, each with their own unique `pagetoken` from the previous response.

Comment: Thank you.  This solves my second question. I can find a way to filter by the types. But the documentation states that **`pagetoken` returns up to 20 results from a previously run search.**  What would be the trick to fetch more than 20 results?

Comment: The final part of my question answers this. Every API call will return a page token if more results are available. You then need to make another API call with that page token. Read this for more info, https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging. Mark this question correct if this helped you!